# Is it possible to update back through the point of adding subrepos?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I've had a folder in my repository. Then I have made this folder a subrepository (with the very same files), commited and pushed this change. Now I can't update back through that commit. Here's the message I get:

```
% hg update --repository <path to repo> --config ui.merge=internal:fail --rev 1159 --clean
abort: path 'subrepo\include\header.h' is inside nested repo 'subrepo'
[command returned code 255 Wed Dec 05 11:57:45 2012]
```

Where `subrepo` is the name of that folder where subrepo now resides.
Any way to defeat this and update to earlier revision?

Comment: I've just had a "play" with mercurial, and it looks like trying to do an update back to before you had the subrepo puts the working directory in an "odd" state. For example, doing an `hg update -C` afterwards tries to restore the files, but doesn't set the working directory state correctly (for me). `hg summary` reports the parents are `-1:000000000000` with no revisions checked out. I'm currently thinking this could be a bug report - will play some more...

Comment: @icabod: thanks for your time, hoping for further findings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution: delete the folder in question, then update with the "discard changes" option. Works like charm.

Comment: Note, however, that deleting that folder has the potential to lose any changes that were made locally in that subrepo repository.  It sounds like that wasn't a problem in your case, but it could cause major problems if someone else did this without realizing the potential for data loss.

Comment: @davidmc24: Good point, although it should be obvious to any Mercurial user that changes that were not commited AND pushed will be lost. And I don't see any problem commiting and pushing changes to that subrepository regardless of the main repo state.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of googling, this looks like it's directly related to [Caveat 3](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Caveats), to quote "Update/merge currently can't remove subrepositories entirely as that might lose local-only changes". Also caveat 5 states "Collisions between normal files and subrepos are not handled".

Interestingly, and something I'd not seen before, Subrepositories are considered a "[feature of last resort](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort)", which is to say something you should try not to use if you can help it.

Probably not the answer you were looking for.

A workaround is to get to your revision by cloning... you can use a new clone based on a revision just before you created the subrepo:

```
% hg clone --repository <path to repo> new_copy --rev 1159
```

This will clone everything up to that point, so you will lose any "future history", but will at least be able to get back to an earlier version.

Comment: Oh well. If only I knew about those caveats... Thank you.

Comment: You can clone the repo up to the previous version, but haven't found a way to update within the same repo.

Comment: Perfect! I was suspecting it should be possible, but didn't find the command yet. That'll do the trick.

Comment: Found a solution, see my answer if interested.